# Meaning of "test do" syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm sorry if my question is silly because I just want to ask what does below line meaning in Ruby. (I'm reading a book about Rails as fast as possible for my course, so I don't have a firm grasp on the Ruby language.)

Here is a piece of code for unit test purpose:

```
class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "product attributes must not be empty" do   // this line I don't know
    product = Product.new
    assert product.invalid?
    assert product.errors[:title].any?
    assert product.errors[:description].any?
    assert product.errors[:price].any?
    assert product.errors[:image_url].any?
  end
```

The thing I want to ask is: At the line I don't know, the syntax  `test "...." do`, what does it mean? Is it a function, method, class, something else?

Comment: You should learn Ruby *before* you learn Rails. If you don't understand the language the framework is built on, then you'll never be able to fully utilize the framework. And don't rush the learning process!

Comment: I'm sorry so much. I'm just has a quick tutorial about Ruby and when I change to really really big Ruby enviroment (Rails), it makes me scare :( The big problem is I don't have many times for upcoming course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stuff is called a class macro, fancy name for a simple mechanism:

It is a class method (def self.test), that way you can use it in you class definition directly for example.

The normal way to write test cases (in Test::Unit) would be more like this:

```
def test_something_interesting
  ...
end
```

However, ActiveSupport (part of Rails) provides you this syntactical sugar so that you can write it like this:

```
test "something interesting" do
  ...
end
```

This method will then define a method with the name test_something_interesting.

You can find the implementation in Rails:

```
activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/declarative.rb
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I create something like that ? Thanks :)

Comment: @hqt - It's called a Ruby DSL (Domain Specific Language). Basically it means you are writing code that will extended the original language with some new constructs. The best way for you to learn it is to [google it](http://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+dsl).

Answer (score 2):

It's a block. Somewhere in the testing framework this method is defined:

```
def test(description, &block)
  # do something with block
end
```

I **highly** recommend that you pick a good Ruby book and that you read it *slowly*.

Comment: can you tell me a bit more please. According to some tutorial I have read. the function should be : `def test(description)`. why you put `&block` to this function (although if I remember, it mean block is optional). ?

Comment: Yes, a block is the `do end` syntax. It could also be `{}`. You can read more about block here: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_blocks.html